# How Can I open a new activity when an ImageButton is clicked on in the listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

How Can I open a new activity when an ImageButton is clicked on in the listview? At the moment my OnClickListener is in my ArrayAdapter class but from there i can't start a new activity. So how can i get the OnClickListener in my MainActivity and how can i handle there "name" and "ID"?

Heres my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MessageArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageHome> {

private TextView playername;
private ImageView profile;
private ImageButton chat;
private List<MessageHome> MessageList = new ArrayList<MessageHome>();
private LinearLayout singleMessageContainer;

@Override
public void add(MessageHome object) {
    MessageList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

public MessageArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}


public int getCount() {
    return this.MessageList.size();
}

public MessageHome getItem(int index) {
    return this.MessageList.get(index);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage, parent, false);
    }
    singleMessageContainer = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
    MessageHome chatMessageObj = getItem(position);
    playername = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.playername_);
    playername.setText(chatMessageObj.name);
    final String ID = chatMessageObj.ID;
    final String name = chatMessageObj.name;
    profile = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    if(chatMessageObj.newm == 1)
        profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.player);
    else
        profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.player2);

    chat = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_message);
    chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("log_tag",name+ID);
            // Here start new activity, but doesn't work here

        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

}

This is my MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    messageArrayAdapter = new MessageArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_message_single);
    listView.setAdapter(messageArrayAdapter);

    listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    listView.setAdapter(messageArrayAdapter);

    //to scroll the list view to bottom on data change
    messageArrayAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            listView.setSelection(messageArrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for the Help ;)

Comment: *OnClickListener is in my ArrayAdapter class but from there i can't start a new activity* Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `Views` have a `Context`:

```
chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("log_tag",name+ID);
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the below line in your activity_chat_singlemessage.xml

```
android:onClick="nameOfFunction"
```

and put this function in your activity

```
 public void nameOfFunction(final View view){
      startActivity(new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in Adapter :

```
private Context context;
public MessageArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
  this.context = context;
}
```

and in your listener :

```
   context.startActivity(new Intent(context,YourNewActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few issues. But first off, you only have one instance of an image button in your adapter. Therefore, I think only the last item in your list will have the image button bound.
You should create a view holder for each item in the list, as you need to bind the event to each item in the list as store the index of the item along with that viewholder. So create an inner class (I'm cutting out some of your details):

```
public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView playerName;
    public ImageButton profileButton;
}
```

In your adpater, getView property handle the viewHolder:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder row;
    if (convert View == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage, parent, false);
        row.playerName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.playername_);
        row.profileButton = (ImageButton)   row.findViewById(R.id.ib_message);
        convertView.setTag(row);
    } else row = (ViewHolder) convertView.GetTag();
   row.setText(chatMessageObj.name);
   row.profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("log_tag",name+ID);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Hopefully enough to get you going. (copied the intent code from asadmshah)